# Fold multiple function-calls to single function?

Tags: c++, simd, api-design

I was thinking about a simple SIMD class, that supports overloaded arithmetic operators `+-*/` etc.
While implementing this as a class template to support different kinds of intrinsics, I noticed that there are some available that would do multiple operations at once (`_mm_fmadd_ps` for multiplication and addition).
I wondered now if there is an *relative sane* way to still use the math-operator overloads
`a * b + c  -> madd( a , b , c )`
instead of using normal free functions
`add( mul( a , b ) , c ) -> madd( a , b , c )`
**and** use these newer intrinsics.

So my question boils down to:

1. Is it possible to *chain* multiple (independent) function-calls to call only one specific function (general question, not SIMD related)?

   - (when proxies are able to do this, are they worth it)?
2. If not, whats a good way to go on api-design regarding a SIMD-container to provide normal operations and also be able to newer intrinsics?

   - provide operator-overloads and free functions at the same time
   - discard operator-overloads and only rely on free functions
3. Is the compiler allowed to fold intrinsics to automatically use the new ones where appropriate? (collapse `add( mul( a , b ) , c )` to `madd( a , b , c )` when intrinsics are available and/or already used for the needed version of intrinsics)

Comment: it can be done if the result of operator * is a proxy object who's operator+ builds the simd call

Comment: Check out [macstl from PixelGlow](http://www.pixelglow.com/macstl/) - this was originally written for AltiVec (PowerPC SIMD) and then ported to SSE I believe, and it has the ability to fold operations through the magic of C++ templates. It's pretty old now, but the implementation ideas are probably still useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this (you'll probably want to use maximum optimiser settings):

```
#include <iostream>

template<class Intrinsic>
struct optimised
{
    using type = Intrinsic;

    optimised(type v)
    : _v (v)
    {}

    operator type&() {
        return _v;
    }

    operator const type&() const {
        return _v;
    }

    type _v;
};

// naiive implementation of madd
double madd(double a, double b, double c) {
    std::cout << "madd(" << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << ")" << std::endl;
    return (a * b) + c;
}

struct mul_result
{
    mul_result(const double& a, const double&b)
    : _a(a), _b(b)
    {}

    operator double() const {
        return _a * _b;
    }

    const double &_a, &_b;    
};

double operator+(const mul_result& ab, const double& c)
{
    return madd(ab._a, ab._b, c);
}

mul_result operator*(const optimised<double>& a, const optimised<double>& b)
{
    return mul_result(a, b);
}

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    optimised<double> a = 3, b = 7, c = 2;

    auto x = a * b + c; 
    cout << x << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
madd(3, 7, 2)                                                                                                                           
23
```

Comment: For something like this with so many function calls, I'd actually recommend force-inlining. Since most compiler optimizers have a heuristic limit to how much they will inline.

Comment: @Mysticial I think we'd want it to do more than force-inline. Ideally we want all those intermediate references optimised completely away. I have no idea how possible that is in reality. Comment from someone who knows would be really welcome.

Comment: In my experience, compiler's are pretty good at optimizing out references to locals. If they're all inlined, they should be locals unless the caller is passing them in from somewhere else.

Comment: yup, checked it with g++ -O3. The entire code is reduced to a multiply and an add. Great, problem solved then :-)